# Problems sending multiple objects through POST and SPRING-MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing REST services which have to receive multiple info. In this case, two objects and an attribute.

This is the javascript where I'm testing the POST request

```
    var user = {
        username: "admin",
        password: "admin"
    };
    var userToSubscribe = {
        username: "newuser",
        password: "newpassword",
        email: "user@1and1.es"
    };

    var openid = "myopenid";

    $.ajax({
        url: '/myportal/rest/subscribeUser.json',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ user: user, userToSubscribe: userToSubscribe, openid: openid})    
    });
```

The POST request:

```
    JSON


    openid
        "myopenid"

    user
        Object { username="admin", password="admin"}

    userToSubscribe
        Object { username="newuser", password="newpassword", email="user@1and1.es"}
    Source
    {"user":{"username":"admin","password":"admin"},"userToSubscribe":{"username":"newuser","password":"newpassword","email":"user@1and1.es"},"openid":"myopenid"}
```

And the controller which handles the POST:

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/subscribeUser.json")
public @ResponseBody Message subscribeUser(@RequestBody("user") User user, @RequestBody("userToSubscribe") User userToSubscribe, @RequestParam String openid){
    ...
}
```

And the error is

POST subscribeUser.json  400 Incorrect request localhost:8080 990 B [::1]:8080

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any exception available in servlet container logs?

Comment: Thanks for answering me @Jk1. There is no exception in the logs. It seems that the POST is malformed and does not reach the controller :/ but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Even if request is rejected before reaching the controller exception is usualy logged. In case of Tomcat (for example) it will go in catalina.out by default. I suggest to look for the server side exception. It may also be some intermediate network agent, like proxy, which is rejecting the request long before the target server.

Comment: If I simplify the method only including the user and the post instead of doing Json.Stringfy including in the data directly: '{"user":{"username":"john","password":"johnjohn"}}' the controller is reached but the object User is not filled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The request body will contain the entire JSON content. So when you want to map the JSON, you use only one RequestBody annotated-parameter. You will have to do something like this:

```
public @ResponseBody Message subscribeUser(@RequestBody String str)
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(str);
```

And then use the convertValue method of the mapper to get your different objects from the string.

```
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(str);
User theUser = mapper.convertValue(node.get("user"), User.class);
```

Similarly for the other objects

Comment: I don't understand why Jackson can't do this when it's mapping the JSON to the controller parameter. It does it in other cases when you have a single model - what's preventing it from doing it here? How come it can handle other @RequestParam's, but not one that's a model if there's any other @RequestParam's?

Comment: No need to create an `ObjectMapper` each time as it is threadsafe. Better to store an `ObjectReader` in a `static` variable as a `final` field.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `@ModelAttribute`s in a RESTful method that accepts JSON.  I believe the proper method is to use @RequestBody, as done [here](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java/).  You will most likely need to wrap the objects in some wrapper class, but I could be wrong there as I have never personally tried to pass multiple JSON objects in one request before.

That said, I think it would be a good idea if you rethought your REST api, removing the JSON arguments and instead passing them in as part of the URI path, if possible.  I would suggest reading through [this blog post](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2010/4/29/rest-isnt-what-you-think-it-is).

Comment: Yes, I realised that ModelAttribute was not correct. I replaced ModelAttribute by RequestBody but it doesn't work as expected. I realised that i can't send multiple objects of different classes with JSON as i want with getElements(RequestBody ObjectType1, RequestBody ObjectType2..). It's possible send a list of the same object or sending different objects but you have to receive them as Map<String,Object>

Comment: You can receive it as a String, then parse the JSON on your own.  However, I still think you should consider simplifying the API and using the URI path as part of the input.

Comment: Would you mind to explain more details about what you are talking about? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a java bean(POJO) containing all the objects like..

```
class JavaBean{
    private User user;
    private UserTOSubscribe  userToSubscribe;
    private Long openId;

    // getter and setter
}
```

and pass this bean in to the Web service. so web service looks like..

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/subscribeUser.json")
public @ResponseBody Message subscribeUser(@RequestBody JavaBean javaBean) {
    ...
}
```