# How to Pass Two Different Json objects and Header bean object to spring mvc controller.?

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp

I have been working with Header and Line Records in Spring MVC.I have header Employee object and Two different Employee Address,Employee Salary details of  Json Objects.I need to send all the three objects.
Object 1 - Employee Header Bean object
Object 2-  Employee Address Json Object
Object 3-  Employee Salary Json Object.

My Question is How to send these objects from Ajax call of jsp and How to receive these objects in the spring mvc controller?

Please help me on this.

Comment: try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654120/problems-sending-multiple-objects-through-post-and-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks for your help