# How to distinguish two request handler methods based on json attributes, like @RequestMapping.params does for request parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have one url endpoint `/example/{id}/update` that takes an HTTP request (PUT) with JSON in its body. The problem is, that this url needs to handle two different json objects.

So I would like to have two different Spring Request Handler Methods to handle this two json objects. If this would be a simple http form request I could use `RequestMapping.params` to separate them:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/example/{id}/update", method=RequestMethod.PUT, params={"a.x", "!b.x"} )
@ResponseBody
public Response updateTypeA(@Valid JsonA a) {...}

@RequestMapping(value="/example/{id}/update" method=RequestMethod.PUT, params={"!a.x", "b.x"} )
@ResponseBody
public Response updateTypeA(@Valid JsonB b) {...}
```

But because my request is one with an json objects in its body (not with parameters) I am not able to get `params` working.

So my question is: **is there a way to distinguish between two request handler methods (for the same URL) based on the existence of json attributes in the request body?**

---

*Of course I could implement my own dispatching request handler method, but this would make everything (validation...) so painful*

Comment: Not an expert here, but typically since a restful webservice tends to expose a "Resource"  Why would you have a single URL handle two different resources?  I would expect needing to handle different fields in the model being populated, but not much more than that.

Comment: You can see below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments   Or you can give some more information on your code

Comment: Matthew Fontana: it is some kind of change requirement in a system where the client/browser send this data (I can not control its behaviour), and the server has to handle it.

Comment: You can see below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571307/spring-mvc-request-mapping-two-urls-with-two-different-parameters

Comment: @Rajdeep: I know the `params` attribute of `@RequestMapping`, but this works only for attributes (GET or Form parameter) but not for json objects in the request body.

Comment: This link might be help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654120/problems-sending-multiple-objects-through-post-and-spring-mvc

Comment: _"I can not control its behaviour"_ But you are in control of the API. If you don't want to provide different URLs then demand different media types. Or define an abstract base class for both classes.

Comment: @zeroflagL: No, in this case: I am just the guy how has to implement that API, there are technical restrictions that makes it impossible to change the client behaviour. So the API is fix, and this API contains also a single point where one URL has to handle two different JSON objects (assume it as some not well done PATCH request)

Comment: You can try differ them by content-types @RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes = "application/vnd.ralph.json.a")